# Glowing Dynamic Text Animation in CSS

Tags: css, text

I want to achieve an effect similar to the [Clash Royale glowing text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xtj65LcdKNI) in CSS.

Looking online I've only found ways to make the text glow, yet not dynamically. Mainly I found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_glowing_text.asp) link which highlights how to make the glowing part, and [this](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-text-animation/) link with many different options to make the text dynamically animated. Is it possible to combine the 2 into that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a background animation with `background-clip: text;`
and the *glow* effect (using `text-shadow`) on a `::before` pseudo element:

```css
body {background: #2d2d2d;  text-align: center; padding: 2rem; }

.text {
  position: relative;
  font: bold 3rem/1.4 'Brush Script MT', cursive;
  letter-spacing: -0.1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fffcb5 0%, #f5a223 30%, #fffcb5 60%, #f5a223 80%, #fffcb5 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #000;
  color: transparent;
  animation: bg 3s linear 0s infinite;
}

.text::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: attr(data-text);
  animation: glow 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {  background-position: 0%; }
  100% { background-position: 200%; }
}

@keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #000, 0 0 1rem #fc55;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #000, 0 0 1.7rem #fa29;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="text" data-text="Stack Overglow">Stack Overglow</span>
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: @Drive4Code edited. Had a duplicate `glow` animation rule :) You're welcome